# How to plot image data versus time with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've captured a set of images for which each column is timestamped. I've concurrently sampled other signals (e.g. gyroscope data) that is also timestamped. I'd like to plot these signals on two vertically aligned subplots that share the time axis.

As far as I understand, I cannot call imshow() twice in a subplot and position each image at a different location along x (they both share the starting position, thus overlapping, and there doesn't seem to be a setting to overcome this):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=1, sharex=True)

ax[0].imshow(np.atleast_2d(I[0][0]).T, cmap=plt.cm.gray, \
                            interpolation='Nearest', aspect='auto')
ax[0].imshow(np.atleast_2d(I[0][1]).T, cmap=plt.cm.gray, \
                            interpolation='Nearest', aspect='auto')
```

After some googling, I've found a potential solution that entails creating extra axes within the top subplot, inside of which I can plot each column:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=1, sharex=True)

ax[0].set_ylabel('Rows')
imax = fig.add_axes(ax[0].get_position().min + \
                [ax[0].get_position().xmax - ax[0].get_position().xmin] + \
                [ax[0].get_position().ymax - ax[0].get_position().ymin], \
                                                                sharey=ax[0])
imax.set_ylim([I.shape[2], 0])
imax.set_axis_off()
imax.imshow(np.atleast_2d(I[0][0]).T, cmap=plt.cm.gray, \
                             interpolation='Nearest', aspect='equal')
```

Although this would allow the flexibility of positioning each column wherever I can move the relevant axis, it's quite a bit of grunt work to find the relative position within the image of each timestamp as displayed by all other plots.

Am I missing an easier way to get this done?

Comment: I think you can do at least some of this with `extent`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `extent` to control where on the axis the image is drawn:

```
ax = gca()
ax.imshow(rand(15,15), extent=[0, .5, 0, .5])
ax.imshow(rand(15,15), extent=[.5, 1,  .5, 1])

ax.set_xlim([0, 1])
ax.set_ylim([0, 1])

plt.draw()
```

The units of extent are data units.

[image]

Comment: I hadn't realized `extent` was so flexible. I'll try to build code around this and will come back when I'm done. Thanks!

Comment: This is just what I needed, although `imshow()` is terribly inefficient and plotting a couple thousand columns this way takes several minutes. @tcaswell Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: @movrev You might want to look at `pcolor` and `pcolormesh` as well.

Comment: I've used `pcolor` in the past, but its performance wasn't great. `pcolormesh` seems promising, although none of them seem to have an option such as `extent`.